# Error: "A deprecated version of GetDevice EndPoint was used" with main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I got an error in my code and I do not really know what is happening, can you help me a bit please?

Here is the code and the error:
Code:

```
`**#Get members from the group
$groupObjectId = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX"
$AzureADDevices = Get-AzADGroupMember -GroupObjectId $groupObjectId

#Retrieve BitLocker keys
$deviceRecords = @()

$deviceRecords = foreach ($device in $AzureADDevices) {
    #Write-Output "Test"
        $url = "https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/Device/$($device.Id)"
        $deviceRecord = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Get
        $deviceRecord
    }

$Devices_BitlockerKey = $deviceRecords.Where({$_.BitlockerKey.count -ge 1})**`
```

Error:

```
*Invoke-RestMethod : {"ClassName":"Microsoft.Portal.Framework.Exceptions.ClientException","Message":"A Deprecated version of GetDevice Endpoint was used.","D
ata":{},"HResult":-2146233088,"XMsServerRequestId":null,"Source":"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.PortalExtension.ADExtension","HttpStatusCode":400,"ClientData":{
}}
En línea: 4 Carácter: 25
+ ... iceRecord = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Get ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand*`
```

As you can see what I am trying to do is to get the informations of devices in a Azure Group to retrieve the BitLocker Keey ID of those devices.

I do not know if is the API that is failing.

Thanks a lot.

I tried with  $url = "https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.us/api/Device/$($device.Id)"
But the error is different now.